# SharePoint list template in two language

Tags: sharepoint, list, templates

I have SharePoint list in which column titles are filled in two languages. When I save this list as template and after create new list from this template. And all columns titles in new list are in default language only. 
Can I modify manifest.xml from *.stp file or original list so that in template (and new list from this template) are column titles in two languages?

---

In the `.stp` template there is only one file (i.e. `manifest.xml`) and this file have attribute `<Language>1049</Language>`, so I think that `.stp` templates don't support localization.

Comment: Are the columns' titles automatically translated when you change the language of the site? Can you save a list template, switch the site language and then save a 2nd list template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the `.stp` templates do not support localization ([contrary to the `.wsp` ones](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/4533/950)).

An `.stp` file is actually a `.cab`file so you can decompress it. You will get a `manifest.xml` file and a few `.000` files. Most of them, but but not all **(!)**, are `.zip` files so you can decompress them, get a lot of folders and `.xml` files - try to analyze them, maybe you'll find a find to localize them.

---

If you want to change the `<Language>` attribute of an `.stp` file (with decompressing and then compressing the file manually), you can use the KWizCom's [SharePoint Site Template Language Converter utility](http://www.kwizcom.com/free-downloads/sharepoint-stp-language-converter/).

Comment: Thank You! In article about localization wsp templates speak about only default site templates or I can save my own site as template and then

Comment: @DmitryMelnikov Is it possible to save a SharePoint 2007 site template as a `.wsp` file? As far as I remember, it's not.

Comment: I use SharePoint 2010, and in it I can save site in template only in .wsp file

Comment: @DmitryMelnikov I haven't tried to localize such site templates, but I cannot see why it shouldn't work.